# Turning a PC into an NPC

Tags: dnd-4e

I can't recall if there are rules or guidelines when converting a player character into a monster with an XP value and proper abilities so they are not over-powered. If someone could tell me if they exist or where they are, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much experience should a PC be worth?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8746/how-much-experience-should-a-pc-be-worth)

Comment: There are no rules here, there are some very good guidelines in the question I've linked above.

Comment: Another term of art for this is "Companion Character".

Comment: @waxeagle - don't really consider it a duplicate as the other question is towards how many XP is a PC worth, and this one is how to make a PC into a comparable NPC.

Comment: It depends on whether you want to turn him into a simple Companion Character to follow the adventurers along and just not have his full complement of abilities ... or if you plan on using him as an enemy in a combat encounter. Either way it's probably best to look for an existing creature that has similar abilities and level to the PC you want to convert. Look at the guide for [Companion Characters in DM2](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ex/20090821). You'll need the actual book for the conversion tables.

Answer (score 3):

In the Dungeon Master Guide there are some rules when creating NPCs, you should just pick the more important powers for this NPC when he was a PC, and make him likely to ressemble the PC.
He will lose some features and powers, but you can manage to make the NPC stronger, but a PC will always be stronger than a NPC in the same level.

Check out the rules to create a NPC: Dungeon Master Guide pages 186-188.