# How Much XP is an NPC worth?

Tags: dnd-4e, encounter-design, npc, experience-points

I'm trying to add an NPC (as explained on pages 186-188 of the DMG) to a DnD 4e encounter, and I'm having trouble finding any information on how much XP to subtract from the XP budget for the encounter. If I have a 2nd level NPC, is it comparable to a standard 2nd level monster (i.e. 125 XP)? Or is it closer to an elite monster (250 XP)? Or is it something that varies according to the NPC's build?

Comment: NPCs should be built as monsters, not as players. The **only** things that use the PC rules are the PCs.

Comment: Related (but not duplicate, on further thought): http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8746/how-much-experience-should-a-pc-be-worth

Comment: Yes, I've seen that other one, but it doesn't answer the question I'm asking. And I'm not building the NPC as a player. I'm building it according to the rules on pages 186-188 of the DMG. But unless I'm missing something, I don't see any explanation for how they compare to monsters of the same level.

Comment: @nai888 monster = NPC in 4e.

Comment: Why the -1 to the question?

Comment: @nai888 Do you have access to DDI tools? I would highly suggest using the monster builder there if you do.

Comment: If you built the NPC using the monster design rules, then they're worth however much XP the monster you built them as is worth.

Comment: @ObliviousSage That would be if I were creating a monster (pages 184-185 of the DMG), but I'm referring to creating an NPC (pages 186-188 of the DMG, where it describes how to create an NPC and how to give it stats for combat). I was thinking that I would need to create an NPC since he's a dwarf, not a monstrous race, but I'm now realizing that you're right, and it would be much easier to design him as a monster even though he's a dwarf.

Comment: Is the NPC fighting FOR the party? Or AGAINST the party?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How much XP a monster or NPC is worth is determined by it's role and level.

If you're designing a L1 Solo that's a 500 XP NPC. If you're designing a L5 elite then that's 400 XP.

What the NPC is worth is defined by *your design* and is based on *what kind of NPC* you are making.

Generally you only determine these things if you intend for your PCs to enter combat with your NPC.

When an NPC is going to enter combat, he is based on the same rules that monsters are based on. In fact if you want a quick way to make a reasonably designed NPC, grab a monster of the role and level that you'd like to use and just reskin his character and powers to be your NPC.